# Cannot upgrade to ubuntu 14.10 from ubuntu 14.04

Tags: upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I tried upgrading to ubuntu 14.10 using this command:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

And this is my console it cuts off the beginning but only a little bit:

http://pastebin.com/dUQ02VhK

I have no idea what is going on!  It was much easier upgrading from 12.04 to 14.04!

Note that I have `Prompt=normal` in `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`.

Comment: Whats the output of `grep '^Prompt' /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` ?

Comment: The output is: Prompt=normal

Answer (score 0):

First take care of the GPG error. Then edit your /etc/apt/sources.list and disable all lines that don't contain a reference to 'ubuntu.com', these are for example all the lines that contain a reference to Launchpad PPA's. Then try to upgrade again. If this works reenable the lines you've diabled and do a regular update.

Comment: I don't even know what a GPG error is ):

Comment: You did not import the key that belongs to the repository mentioned. The key certfies that the repository is the one it claims to be. Without the key you get the GPG error. If you don't know how to import the key then edit the sources list as I proposed and proceed. This will temporarily solve the error because then the repository that causes the warning is disabled.

Comment: There was nothing in there that doesn't contain a reference to ubuntu.com.  Here is my sources.list: http://pastebin.com/XCebRvPq

Comment: Are there any other files in /etc/apt. In the first pastebin I see several references to Launchpad repositories and to a Dropbox repository. You have to get rid of those at least temporarily.

Comment: This is my /etc/apt folder: http://imgur.com/oBaC3fO

Comment: What's inside the folder /etc/apt/sources.list.d

Comment: These are the contents of etc/apt/sources.list.d: http://imgur.com/OTC8RQX

Comment: Move all of these to a location outside /etc/apt then try to upgrade again.

Comment: So I got the same error but I found another folder with similar stuff in and moved it, I will tell you how that goes soon.

Comment: Yes, let me know the result.

Comment: It still failed, I have given up.  Thanks so much for trying though.

Comment: There are still options. If you want to do another attempt then do this command: sudo install aptitude which will install aptitude and a bunch of additional things. If this works then do: sudo aptitude safe-upgrade then reboot and then do: sudo aptitude full-upgrade and reboot if any of these results in interesting messages please let me know. If it works I would like to hear it too.

Comment: The commands run normally, there are no interesting messages.  I just tried upgrading again and it still does not work.

Comment: Just tried deleting apt.log, still no luck.

Comment: Finally! Got it to work, turns out it was some old runescape package.  Thanks!